# fromEvent rxjs Angular 5 is not properly working

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I have create radio buttons from an array i.e

```
['Yes','No']
<mat-radio-group class="tt" style="display: inline-block" formControlName="recursive" >
<div class="opt" *ngFor="let t of tarrif_type_arr">
<mat-radio-button value={{t}} name="recursive" #recursive id="recursive" [checked]="checked" >{{t}</mat-radio-button>      
</div>
</mat-radio-group>
```

And now i want to listen for the click event of my recursive element
i tried using

```
@ViewChild('recursive',{ read: ElementRef }) recur:ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit()
{
let clickObservable$=fromEvent(this.recur.nativeElement,'click').subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res);
})
}
```

but the issue i am facing is its triggering the event only for first option i.e yes whenever i click on Yes it shows

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 2084, screenY: 410, clientX: 498, clientY: 308, …}
```

but it doesn't even check or console.log when click on No

Comment: Try with `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`.

Comment: Why aren't you using [`FormBuilder`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#generating-form-controls-with-formbuilder)? Then you can let Angular generate inputs for you and capture their inputs through Angular.

Answer (score 1):

As @ConnorsFan says you have to use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`.

For example the typed version:

```
@ViewChildren(MatRadioButton) recur: QueryList<MatRadioButton>;
ngAfterViewInit()
{
  this.recur.forEach(c => {
    // here your goal
    fromEvent(c._nativeElement,'click').subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    });
  })  
}
```

or direct interact with ElementRef:

```
@ViewChildren(MatRadioButton, { read: ElementRef }) recur: QueryList<ElementRef>;
ngAfterViewInit()
{
  this.recur.forEach(c => {
    // here your goal
    fromEvent(c.nativeElement,'click').subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    });
  })  
}
```